# запись и чтение вектора структуры

Tags: c++

Написал небольшую программу для тестов работы с векторами и чтением-записью. Смысл: при запуске файл копируется в вектор, с ним можно работать, добавлять-удалять.

При первом запуске, когда вектор пуст, все работает: могу добавить хоть сколько структур в цикле, а при втором запуске при попытке добавления в вектор происходит ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
>
> _Pnext было 0x50C274.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
struct Administrator
{
    std::string login_admin;
    std::string pass_admin;
};
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::fstream file;//создание файла и запись его
    char komanda;
    int kol_adminov = 0;
 
    //считывание данных по администраторам при первом включении если их нет то запрашиваем ввод
    file.open("avtoriz_admin_kol.ser", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if ( file.is_open() )//проверка существует файл или нет
    {
        file >> kol_adminov;
        std::cout << "kol_adminov - " << kol_adminov << '\n';
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "В базе нет записей админов введите их " << '\n';
    }
    //создание массива структур админов
    std::vector<Administrator> baza_admin(kol_adminov);
    Administrator adm;//создание временной структуры ввода
    std::cout << "vector<Administrator> baza_admin(kol_adminov) создана кол элементов - " << kol_adminov << '\n';
 
    //открываем файл с базой админов
    file.open("avtoriz_admin.ser", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if ( file.is_open() )//проверка существует файл или нет
    {
        for ( int aa = 0; aa < kol_adminov; ++aa )//чтение файла в вектор
        {
            file.read((char*)&baza_admin[aa], sizeof(baza_admin[aa]));
            std::cout << "baza_admin[0].login_admin - " << aa << baza_admin[aa].login_admin << '\n';
            std::cout << "baza_admin[0].pass_admin - " << baza_admin[aa].pass_admin << '\n';
        }
        file.close();
    }
    do//бесконечный цикл ожидания ввода админов
    {
        std::cout << "Введите команду" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> komanda;
        switch ( komanda )
        {
        case 'l':
        {
            int a = baza_admin.size();//узнаем количество элементов в векторе
            std::cout << "Введите логин администратора a = " << a << "  " << adm.login_admin << '\n';
            std::cin >> adm.login_admin;//чтение с клавы в структуру ввода
            std::cout << "Введите пароль администратора a = " << a << '\n';
            std::cin >> adm.pass_admin;//чтение с клавы в структуру ввода
 
            baza_admin.push_back(adm);//добавление в конец вектора структуры
/*вот на этом виснет при повторном запуске... при первом можно создавать несколько элементов*/
 
            file.open("avtoriz_admin.ser", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::app); //открытие файла для записи 
            if ( file.is_open() )//проверка существует файл или нет
            {
                file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&baza_admin[a]), sizeof baza_admin[a]);//запись вектора в файл
                std::cout << "baza_admin[0].login_admin - " << baza_admin[a].login_admin << '\n';
                std::cout << "baza_admin[a].pass_admin - " << baza_admin[a].pass_admin << '\n';
                file.close();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "файл с логином админа не записан - " << '\n';
            }
            file.open("avtoriz_admin_kol.ser", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary); //открытие файла для записи 
            if ( file.is_open() )//проверка существует файл или нет
            {
                file << ++a;
                file.close();
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
        }
    }
    while ( true );
 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но вот он же читает файл:

```
vector<Administrator> baza_admin(kol_adminov) создана кол элементов - 4
baza_admin[0].login_admin - 0  rrrrrrr
baza_admin[0].pass_admin - 1111
baza_admin[1].login_admin - 1  ddddd
baza_admin[1].pass_admin - 222
baza_admin[2].login_admin - 2  gghhhh
baza_admin[2].pass_admin - 445
baza_admin[3].login_admin - 3  rfvgrbggf
baza_admin[3].pass_admin - 445433356334456
```

считан и выведен в консоль вектор из 4 структур по 2 элемента. ошибку-то не выдал чтения.

Ошибка вылетает при попытке добавить в вектор новый элемент:

```
baza_admin.push_back(adm);
```

при этом, если файлов нет, т.е., первый запуск программы, то тут ошибок нет.

Использовал VS 2015

[ссылка](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DbHA/Eg4TXHL7s) на создаваемый файл

Comment: А Вы знаете о существовании такого инструмента как отладчик?

Comment: покажите пример файла

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум ошибка в этой строке

```
file.read((char*)&baza_admin[aa], sizeof(baza_admin[aa]));
```

Причем ошибка "двойная". Вы рассчитываете, что sizeof возвратит Вам размер строки. А он возвратит в данном случае 4. Соответственно, read пытается прочитать 4 байта в строку, но "строка этого не ожидает" - там нет места для этого.

Но здесь есть ещё одна потенциальная бага. Вы считаете, что данные в std::string размещаются "непрерывным куском". А это не совсем так. Точнее раньше было не так. Стандарт с++03 гарантирует это только для std::vector, а для строки - нет (хотя по факту все существующие реализации std::string используют непрерывный участок памяти). Современные стандары уже требуют, что бы строка была в памяти непрерывным блоком (пункт 24.1). Поэтому, если компилятор старый (а я знаю много любителей BorlandC++ 5.5 !), нужно смотреть аккуратно.

Что бы сделать все правильно, есть несколько способов. Первый, простой - писать вначале размер строки (используя метод length  для получения размера), а потом саму строку (используя `c_str()` для получения указателя). Соответственно, когда читаем, нужно прочитать размер, вычитать в буффер, а потом уложить в строку.

Более простой способ - писать каждую строку отдельно. В этом случае чтение-запись сильно упрощается, более того, файл будет доступен для модификации обычным блокнотом.  Я лично рекомендую этот способ для начинающих. Формат записи - по две строки на каждую запись. Размер списка можно записать в самое начало.

Более сложные способы, но более "продакшн" - использовать сериализатор, например json, xml, protobuf и другие.

Comment: Данные в std::string располагаются непрерывным куском: _«The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any basic_string
object s, the identity &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n shall hold for all values of n such that 0
<= n < s.size().»_ **[string.require]p4**

Comment: В стандарте с++03 такого не было.  На [rsdn](https://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2054852.all) есть комментарии на эту тему.  И Маерс и Метью Уилсон писали также на эту тему.

Новый стандарт я на эту  тему не проверял.

Comment: @KoVadim Стандарт c++03 уже как дважды устарел. ТС, конечно, вполне мог использовать старую версию языка, но отдельно он это всё-таки не упомянул. Я, например, стараюсь придерживаться современной версии Стандарта при обсуждении, если это не указано дополнительно.

Comment: Согласен полностью, но все известные мне компиляторы, если им явно  не указать `-std=c++11` или что то подобное, используют старый синтаксис. Поэтому, у ТС скорее всего старый синтаксис.

Пока только новые версии QtCreator при создании нового проекта явно прописывают использование 11 стандарта.

Comment: @KoVadim студийный компилятор (а судя по всему, его как раз и использует ТС) не требует явного указания ключей стандарта для работы в режиме `c++11`. Да и `clang` съедает, но с предупреждениями. А вот `g++` действительно хочет явного указания и выдает ошибки без этого.

Comment: у студии много версий:) 2012-2013 требуют.

Comment: @KoVadim Опять таки, рассматривать надо современные версии. Вы же не будете утверждать про ключ `c++11` для какой-нибудь VS2005. А VS2013 у меня например не требует явного ключа. Если у Вас требует - скажите, какой. Интересно посмотреть.

Comment: я использую студийный компилятор с под QtCteator - там компилятор от 2015 студии пока нельзя использовать - ещё не собрали qt под него (официально).

Comment: @KoVadim, студия не требует никаких ключей, просто в разных версиях разная степень поддержки. Но, я всё равно не понимаю, какое отношение это имеет к тому, что теперь стандарт де факто, стал стандартом де юре. Строка всегда была единым блоком, просто по какой-то причине это не включили в ранний стандарт, о котором, в настоящее время, имеет смысл говорить лишь в прошедшем времени и не стоит включать информацию из него в ответы 2016 года. Я понимаю, что Вы не знали, что положение изменилось, но я ведь указал Вам на это. Почему бы не исправить ответ?

Answer (score 1):

KoVadim Вам уже написал, как лучше писать в файл, поэтому я повторяться не стану. Я напишу Вам, в чём Ваша ошибка(KoVadim ошибку описал не совсем точно).
Итак, ошибка у Вас в этой строке:

```
file.read((char*)&baza_admin[aa], sizeof(baza_admin[aa]));
```

Смотрите, что Вы делаете: берёте буфер строки, созданной конструктором по умолчанию, которая может быть пустой(если это студия, то она не будет пустой, будет использована т.н. small string optimization, т.е. строка будет иметь какой-то буфер, порядка 16 байтов, в стеке). Но не нужно надеяться на это, стандарт это не гарантирует, а значит мы должны поступать так, как будто бы строка пуста, а значит использование этого буфера невозможно в том виде, в котором Вы его используете.

Идём дальше, Вы говорите компьютеру: прочитай мне из файла `sizeof(baza_admin[aa])` байтов и запиши их в буфер(который, как мы выяснили мы как бы не имеем права использовать). Сколько будет `sizeof(baza_admin[aa])`? Не имею не малейшего понятия,— это зависит от реализации. Более того, я уверен, что это совершенно не то, что Вы имели в виду. Так строки никто и никогда не пишет — это не правильно. Размер `std::string` может включать в себя какие угодно внутренние члены, которые к самой строке имеют лишь косвенное отношение. Более того, в общем случае, сама строка будет располагаться в куче(heap) и этот размер попросту не будет учтён в `sizeof`.

В итоге мы имеем, что у Вас некорректное чтение и некорректная запись строк. Как это у Вас работает? Совпадение многих факторов, но Ваша программа неверна. Поэтому Вам нужно поправить как запись, так и чтение. Как поправить? Воспользоваться советами из поста KoVadim'а. С моей точки зрения проще всего писать строки в текстовый файл и читать из него же. Каждая строка с новой строки.